# Copying (clonning and deleting original) Ads with minimal changes using AdWords API (PHP Client Library)

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I need to add my tags to all AdWords Ads' `$trackingUrlTemplate` [CreativeTrackingUrlTemplate](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201802/AdGroupAdService?wsdl) for types of Ad that support it in order to track them with my tracker too without changing any other Ad's property and finally save their ids in my tracker's database.

First, i simply tried to get all Ads, set property, save Ads, use Ad ids. it's not worked because:
1) You can only change status of Ad; for all other parameters you have to create new Ad with desired property values set and remove original Ad.
2) To retrieve Ad object from `AdGroupAdService` you have to specify each property of `Selector`, otherwise you get "shallow" Ads retrieved.

So, in general, i retrieve the Ad object, modify it and send back using `Operator::ADD` and remove it using `Operator::REMOVE` operator.

Ok, (1) can be solved by analyzing result of "ADD" operation:
`$adGroupAdService->mutate([$operation])->getValue()[0]->getAd()->getId()`

To solve (2) i used following algorithm:
I) goto [docs](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201802)
II) Set "id=my" for `AdGroupAdService` table from the page in HTML firebug editor and launch following script in firebug console to get the list with properties and comments to them

```
var t = $("#my")
$.each($("tr", t), (i, v) => { console.log("'" + $("td", v).eq(0).text() + "', //" + $("a", $("td", v).eq(1)).text()); });
```

III) Copy/Paste result in `$selector->setFields([])` parameters
IV) Manually remove duplicate and empty entries.

Second, i faced that [ImageAd](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/e3aecd77aa239bde84361a729a6e6235b1fe36d1/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201802/cm/ImageAd.php) `image` property populated with "shallow" [Image](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/e3aecd77aa239bde84361a729a6e6235b1fe36d1/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201802/cm/Image.php) object with empty `data` property. So, tried to use `adToCopyImageFrom` property and set it so:

```
if ($api_ad->getAd() instanceof Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\ImageAd) {
  $api_ad->getAd()->setAdToCopyImageFrom($api_ad->getAd()->getId());
}
```

but got following [error](https://gist.github.com/fredeom/841d9ea7fcdd7d75c560a7363ff93194): `[AdError.IMAGE_ERROR @ operations[0].operand.ad]`.
Moreover, its not clear what [use this field to specify an existing image ad to copy the image from](https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201802/AdGroupAdService?wsdl) means exactly (id?, image object? both not working).

So, to clone this particular image i had to do following workaround:

```
foreach ($api_ad->getAd()->getImage()->getUrls() as $url) {
  if ($url->getKey() == "FULL") {
    $image = new Image();
    $image->setData(file_get_contents($url->getValue()));
    $image->setType(MediaMediaType::IMAGE);
    $mediaService = $adWordsServices->get($session, MediaService::class);
    $api_ad->getAd()->setImage($mediaService->upload([$image])[0]);
  }
}
```

It uses too much insights i dont want to depend on and its strange that [ResponsiveDisplayAd](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/e3aecd77aa239bde84361a729a6e6235b1fe36d1/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201802/cm/ResponsiveDisplayAd.php) which have image fields (`marketingImage`, `logoImage`, `squareMarketingImage`) too doesn't have such problem.

Third, i faced following problem with [GmailAd](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/e3aecd77aa239bde84361a729a6e6235b1fe36d1/src/Google/AdsApi/AdWords/v201802/cm/GmailAd.php): `[RequiredError.REQUIRED @ operations[0].operand.ad.`**marketingImageDisplayCallToAction**`.text]` but where is no special warning about selector for this field in AdGroupAdService.wsdl and it can be retrieved using `$api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->getText()`
On the screenshot of my adwords ui gmail ad view you can see that this option is switched off and therefore empty `https://pp.userapi.com/c840220/v840220718/8aba3/cvS4wSxVeVk.jpg`
I tried the following code with the exact same error:

```
if (null == $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->getText()) {
    $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->setText("");
}
```

if i try something like following it works fine but breaks the rule "Dont change anything in original Ad object except `trackingUrlTemplate`":

```
if (null == $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->getText()) {
    $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->setText("SHOULD_NOT_BE"); // THERE
}
```

So, here the end of the story because i cant dig deeper without solving or workaround this showstopper.

Full code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAd;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAdOperation;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\AdGroupAdService;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\Configuration;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Operator;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\Image;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\MediaMediaType;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\MediaService;

$config = new Configuration([
    'LOGGING' => [
        'reportDownloaderLogLevel' => 'NOTICE',
        'soapLogLevel' => 'NOTICE'
    ],
    'ADWORDS' => [
        'developerToken' => 'DEVELOPER_TOKEN',
        'clientCustomerId' => 'CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID'
    ],
    'OAUTH2' => [
        'clientId' => 'CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'clientSecret' => 'CLIENT_SECRET',
        'refreshToken' => 'REFRESH_TOKEN'
    ]
]);

$oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())->from($config)->build();
$session = (new AdWordsSessionBuilder())->from($config)->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)->build();

$adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
$campaignService = $adWordsServices->get($session, CampaignService::class);

$selector = new Selector();

$selector->setFields(['Id', 'Name', 'Status', 'AdvertisingChannelType']);
$api_campaigns = $campaignService->get($selector);

foreach ($api_campaigns->getEntries() as $api_campaign) {
    echo $api_campaign->getName() . "\n";
}

$adGroupAdService = $adWordsServices->get($session, AdGroupAdService::class);
$selector = new Selector();

// https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#v201802
// 1. Set "id=my" for desired table from the page in HTML firebug editor and launch following script in firebug console
// to get the list with properties and comments to them
// var t = $("#my")
// $.each($("tr", t), (i, v) => { console.log("'" + $("td", v).eq(0).text() + "', //" + $("a", $("td", v).eq(1)).text()); });
// 2. Copy/Paste result in $selector->setFields below
// 3. Manually remove duplicate and empty entries
$selector->setFields([
    'AccentColor', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.accentColor debugger eval code:1:32
    'AdGroupId', //AdGroupAd.adGroupId debugger eval code:1:32
    'AdType', //Ad.type debugger eval code:1:32
    'AdvertisingId', //Video.advertisingId debugger eval code:1:32
    'AllowFlexibleColor', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.allowFlexibleColor debugger eval code:1:32
    'Automated', //Ad.automated debugger eval code:1:32
    'BaseAdGroupId', //AdGroupAd.baseAdGroupId debugger eval code:1:32
    'BaseCampaignId', //AdGroupAd.baseCampaignId debugger eval code:1:32
    'BusinessName', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.businessName debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdBusinessName', //CallOnlyAd.businessName debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdCallTracked', //CallOnlyAd.callTracked debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdConversionTypeId', //CallOnlyAd.conversionTypeId debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdCountryCode', //CallOnlyAd.countryCode debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdDescription1', //CallOnlyAd.description1 debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdDescription2', //CallOnlyAd.description2 debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdDisableCallConversion', //CallOnlyAd.disableCallConversion debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdPhoneNumber', //CallOnlyAd.phoneNumber debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallOnlyAdPhoneNumberVerificationUrl', //CallOnlyAd.phoneNumberVerificationUrl debugger eval code:1:32
    'CallToActionText', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.callToActionText debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreationTime', //Media.creationTime debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreativeFinalAppUrls', //Ad.finalAppUrls debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreativeFinalMobileUrls', //Ad.finalMobileUrls debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreativeFinalUrls', //Ad.finalUrls debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreativeTrackingUrlTemplate', //Ad.trackingUrlTemplate debugger eval code:1:32
    'CreativeUrlCustomParameters', //Ad.urlCustomParameters debugger eval code:1:32
    'Description', //ExpandedDynamicSearchAd.description ExpandedTextAd ResponsiveDisplayAd
    'Description1', //TextAd.description1 DynamicSearchAd
    'Description2', //TextAd.description2 DynamicSearchAd
    'DevicePreference', //Ad.devicePreference debugger eval code:1:32
    'Dimensions', //Media.dimensions debugger eval code:1:32
    'DisplayUploadAdGmailTeaserBusinessName', //GmailTeaser.businessName debugger eval code:1:32
    'DisplayUploadAdGmailTeaserDescription', //GmailTeaser.description debugger eval code:1:32
    'DisplayUploadAdGmailTeaserHeadline', //GmailTeaser.headline debugger eval code:1:32
    'DisplayUploadAdGmailTeaserLogoImage', //GmailTeaser.logoImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'DisplayUrl', //Ad.displayUrl debugger eval code:1:32
    'ExpandingDirections', //ThirdPartyRedirectAd.expandingDirections debugger eval code:1:32
    'FileSize', //Media.fileSize debugger eval code:1:32
    'FormatSetting', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.formatSetting debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailHeaderImage', //GmailAd.headerImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailMarketingImage', //GmailAd.marketingImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailTeaserBusinessName', //GmailTeaser.businessName debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailTeaserDescription', //GmailTeaser.description debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailTeaserHeadline', //GmailTeaser.headline debugger eval code:1:32
    'GmailTeaserLogoImage', //GmailTeaser.logoImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'Headline', //TextAd.headline debugger eval code:1:32
    'HeadlinePart1', //ExpandedTextAd.headlinePart1 debugger eval code:1:32
    'HeadlinePart2', //ExpandedTextAd.headlinePart2 debugger eval code:1:32
    'Height', //Dimensions.height debugger eval code:1:32
    'Id', //Ad.id debugger eval code:1:32
    'ImageCreativeName', //ImageAd.name debugger eval code:1:32
    'IndustryStandardCommercialIdentifier', //Video.industryStandardCommercialIdentifier debugger eval code:1:32
    'IsCookieTargeted', //ThirdPartyRedirectAd.isCookieTargeted debugger eval code:1:32
    'IsTagged', //ThirdPartyRedirectAd.isTagged debugger eval code:1:32
    'IsUserInterestTargeted', //ThirdPartyRedirectAd.isUserInterestTargeted debugger eval code:1:32
    'Labels', //AdGroupAd.labels debugger eval code:1:32
    'LandscapeLogoImage', //DynamicSettings.landscapeLogoImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'LogoImage', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.logoImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'LongHeadline', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.longHeadline debugger eval code:1:32
    'MainColor', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.mainColor debugger eval code:1:32
    'MarketingImage', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.marketingImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'MarketingImageCallToActionText', //DisplayCallToAction.text debugger eval code:1:32
    'MarketingImageCallToActionTextColor', //DisplayCallToAction.textColor debugger eval code:1:32
    'MarketingImageDescription', //GmailAd.marketingImageDescription debugger eval code:1:32
    'MarketingImageHeadline', //GmailAd.marketingImageHeadline debugger eval code:1:32
    'MediaId', //Media.mediaId debugger eval code:1:32
    'MimeType', //Media.mimeType debugger eval code:1:32
    'Path1', //ExpandedTextAd.path1 debugger eval code:1:32
    'Path2', //ExpandedTextAd.path2 debugger eval code:1:32
    'PolicySummary', //AdGroupAd.policySummary debugger eval code:1:32
    'PricePrefix', //DynamicSettings.pricePrefix debugger eval code:1:32
    'ProductImages', //GmailAd.productImages debugger eval code:1:32
    'ProductVideoList', //GmailAd.productVideoList debugger eval code:1:32
    'PromoText', //DynamicSettings.promoText debugger eval code:1:32
    'ReadyToPlayOnTheWeb', //Audio.readyToPlayOnTheWeb Video
    'ReferenceId', //Media.referenceId debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdCertifiedVendorFormatId', //RichMediaAd.certifiedVendorFormatId debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdDuration', //RichMediaAd.adDuration debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdImpressionBeaconUrl', //RichMediaAd.impressionBeaconUrl debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdName', //RichMediaAd.name debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdSnippet', //RichMediaAd.snippet debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdSourceUrl', //RichMediaAd.sourceUrl debugger eval code:1:32
    'RichMediaAdType', //RichMediaAd.richMediaAdType debugger eval code:1:32
    'ShortHeadline', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.shortHeadline debugger eval code:1:32
    'SourceUrl', //Media.sourceUrl debugger eval code:1:32
    'SquareMarketingImage', //ResponsiveDisplayAd.squareMarketingImage debugger eval code:1:32
    'Status', //AdGroupAd.status debugger eval code:1:32
    'SystemManagedEntitySource', //Ad.systemManagedEntitySource debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateAdDuration', //TemplateAd.duration debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateAdName', //TemplateAd.name debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateAdUnionId', //TemplateAd.adUnionId debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateElementFieldName', //TemplateElementField.name debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateElementFieldText', //TemplateElementField.fieldText debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateElementFieldType', //TemplateElementField.type debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateId', //TemplateAd.templateId debugger eval code:1:32
    'TemplateOriginAdId', //TemplateAd.originAdId debugger eval code:1:32
    'UniqueName', //TemplateElement.uniqueName debugger eval code:1:32
    'Url', //Ad.url debugger eval code:1:32
    'UrlData', //Ad.urlData debugger eval code:1:32
    'Urls', //Media.urls debugger eval code:1:32
    'VideoTypes', //ThirdPartyRedirectAd.videoTypes debugger eval code:1:32
    'Width', //Dimensions.width debugger eval code:1:32
    'YouTubeVideoIdString', //Video.youTubeVideoIdString
]);

$api_ads = $adGroupAdService->get($selector);

foreach ($api_ads->getEntries() as $api_ad) {
    echo $api_ad->getAd()->getType() . ": " . $api_ad->getAd()->getId() . "\n";

    $tmpl = $api_ad->getAd()->getTrackingUrlTemplate();
    if (false === strpos($tmpl, "cid={campaignId}")) {
        if (empty($tmpl)) {
            $api_ad->getAd()->setTrackingUrlTemplate($tmpl . "{lpurl}?cid={campaignId}");
        } elseif (strpos($tmpl, "?") === null) {
            $api_ad->getAd()->setTrackingUrlTemplate($tmpl . "?cid={campaignId}");
        } elseif (empty(explode("?", $tmpl)[1])) {
            $api_ad->getAd()->setTrackingUrlTemplate($tmpl . "cid={campaignId}");
        } else {
            $api_ad->getAd()->setTrackingUrlTemplate($tmpl . "&cid={campaignId}");
        }

        if ($api_ad->getAd() instanceof Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\ImageAd) {
            // adToCopyImageFrom - not working
            // $api_ad->getAd()->setAdToCopyImageFrom($api_ad->getAd()->getId());
            foreach ($api_ad->getAd()->getImage()->getUrls() as $url) {
                if ($url->getKey() == "FULL") {
                    $image = new Image();
                    $image->setData(file_get_contents($url->getValue()));
                    $image->setType(MediaMediaType::IMAGE);

                    $mediaService = $adWordsServices->get($session, MediaService::class);
                    $api_ad->getAd()->setImage($mediaService->upload([$image])[0]);
                }
            }
        } elseif ($api_ad->getAd() instanceof Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\GmailAd) {
            //echo     $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->getText();
            if (null == $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->getText()) {
                $api_ad->getAd()->getMarketingImageDisplayCallToAction()->setText(""); //SHOULD_NOT_BE_THERE
            }
            echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
        }
        $adGroupAd = new AdGroupAd();
        $adGroupAd->setAdGroupId($api_ad->getAdGroupId());
        $adGroupAd->setAd($api_ad->getAd());
        $operation = new AdGroupAdOperation();
        $operation->setOperand($adGroupAd);
        $operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
        try {
            $result = $adGroupAdService->mutate([$operation]);
            var_dump($result->getValue()[0]->getAd()->getId());
            $operation->setOperator(Operator::REMOVE);
            $adGroupAdService->mutate([$operation]);
        } catch (Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201802\cm\ApiException $ae) {
            echo $ae->getMessage1() . "\n";
        }
    }
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Man I'm doing something like you and the solution was easy I'm using the version v201802 (php) and the solution is simple when you create the ad you just not set the image and use the field setAdToCopyImageFrom with the id of the ad.

```
            $ad = new ImageAd();
            $ad->setUrl($data['url']);
            $ad->setDisplayUrl($displayUrls);
            $ad->setFinalUrls($finalUrls);
            $ad->setFinalMobileUrls($finalMobileUrls);
            $ad->setFinalAppUrls($finalAppUrls);
            $ad->setTrackingUrlTemplate($data['trackingUrlTemplate']);
            $ad->setFinalUrlSuffix($data['finalUrlSuffix']);
            $ad->setUrlCustomParameters($urlCustomParameters); //CustomParameters
            $ad->setUrlData($urlData);
            $ad->setAutomated($data['automated']);
            $ad->setDevicePreference($data['devicePreference']);
            $ad->setSystemManagedEntitySource($data['systemManagedEntitySource']);
            $ad->setName($data['name']);
            //To copy the image from existing ad (original)
            $ad->setAdToCopyImageFrom($data['id']);
```

It worked for me, I hope it solve something for you.